# Laravel 5.5 + pusher + echo

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-echo

This is my .env configuration

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher

PUSHER_APP_KEY=*******************

PUSHER_APP_SECRET=*********************

PUSHER_APP_ID=*****
```

This is my bootstrap.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Echo = new Echo({
broadcaster: 'pusher',
key: '****************',
cluster: 'us2',
encrypted: true
});
```

This is my another js file

```
window.Echo.private('channel-1')
        .listen('.server.created', function (e) {
            alert(5)
    });
```

This is my TestEvent file

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('channel-1');
}

public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'server.created';
}
```

This is my channels.php file

```
Broadcast::channel('channel-1', function ($user) {

    return true;
});
```

Also I've created artisan command for fire event. in that file I have

```
event(new TestEvent());
```

It doesn't working without any error. What I should do??

Comment: Since you're using a private channel, are you logged in? [See docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting#authorizing-channels)

Comment: Have you checked at the pusher dashboard if the request arrives there?

Comment: it was a little bug. My driver was log because in my env file was 2 BROADCAST_DRIVER hahahahaha))))

Answer (score 0):

in your event class you should implement ShouldBroadcast or ShouldBroadcastNow (in case you are not using queues).

Comment: This should be a comment instead.